# Mod_rewrite with ".html?variable=" not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website that I successfully use the following url rewrite on:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_r-(.*)/calculator.html$ /calcadd.php?rest_id=$1 [L]
```

As my website has evolved I've decided it would be helpful to be able to pass some additional parameters to this page. So I tried to update the url to include a variable after the .html.  Here's what I tried:

```
    RewriteRule ^(.*)_r-(.*)/calculator.html?ids=(.*)$ /calcadd.php?rest_id=$1&ids=$3 [L]
```

This doesn't work, I get a page not found error. And just in case it wasn't clear, this is NOT a mod_rewrite isn't enabled or whatever problem.  All my other rewrites work just fine, so mod_rewrite is enabled, allow override is ALL, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a query string after after .html?

Comment: If you want to match url params, you need a RewriteCond on `%{QUERY_STRING}`. In such simple cases the QSA flag however suffices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a `QSA` flag here to preserve original query while adding new query parameters:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_r-(.*)/calculator\.html$ /calcadd.php?rest_id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Also remember that you cannot match query string in `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 0):

The `RewriteRule` only consideres the requested url without the querystring by default. You need a `RewriteCond` to achieve what you want:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)_r-(.*)/calculator.html$ /calcadd.php?rest_id=$1&%1 [L]
```

untested.

With `%1`, `%2`, etc. you can inject the patterns matched in the correspondent parenthesized patterns in the `RewriteCond` statement in your `RewriteRule`.

Answer (score 0):

Just leave it the way it was and use this. `QSA` flag means Query String Append. It will will automatically add the query sting to the end of your rewrite.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)_r-(.*)/calculator.html$ /calcadd.php?rest_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```